# Output prediction

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

what shall be the output of: (and why?)

```
printf("%d",2.37);
```

Apparently, printf is a variadic function and we can never know the type of a variable argument list. so we always have to specify the format specifiers manually. 
so, 2.37 would be stored as double according to IEEE standards would be fetched and printed in integer format.
But the output is 0.
What is the reason?

Comment: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ - I am getting this warning and its printing some other value and not 0.

Comment: GCC 64bit: -709751640, GCC 32bit: -1889785610, ICC 64bit: 0, clang: 2056828904... All give a warning without even asking for them though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is undefined behavior. You're passing a `double` argument to a function that expects to retrieve an `int` from its varargs macros, and there's no telling at all what that is going to lead to. In theory, it may even crash (with a calling convention that specifies that variadic arguments of different types are passed in different ways or on different stacks).